# Angularjs ng-repeat issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I hope that someone can help me with this issue. I am new to angularjs. I am trying to create a photo gallery where the initial page is a sheet of thumbnail photos from twitter and instagram created with an angularjs ng-repeat loop. When the user hovers over a image the image fades and a button appears for the user to click. When the button is clicked a light box overlay appears showing the full size image. I have placed the latest version here online: http://www.petermingione.com/my-demo/ and I have copied the code below. I was able to create the thumbnail page using the ng-repeat loop and I am now building out the light-box portion of the app. That is the overlay that you see when you click on the view button.  As you can see regardless of which image you click on the only image that appears is the first image in the collection. This is seems to be a problem with ng-repeat. The image is located in each object as mainImage.url and I am accessing it through x.mainImage.url in the loop. I am not sure why it isn't working. Any help that anyone can give me would be greatly appreciated. The code is below and online:

```
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    h1, 
    h2{
        margin-left:10px;
    }

    .outer-wrapper{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .inner-wrapper{
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
        padding:5px;
        position:relative;
    }
    .inner-wrapper img{
        width:100%;
    }
    .inner-wrapper .outer-caption{
        color:black;
        width:100%;
        padding-top:35%;
        background-color:#fc7cab;
        position:relative;
    }
    .inner-wrapper .outer-caption .inner-caption{
        font-size:14px;
        font-family:sans-serif;
        overflow:hidden;
        width:75%;
        height:70px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        margin:auto;
    }
    .inner-wrapper .item-overlay-color{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        margin:auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        transition: all .5s;
        opacity: 0.0;   
    }
    .inner-wrapper:hover .item-overlay-color {
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
    .inner-wrapper .item-overlay-text{
        border: 2px solid #7e7e7e;
        color:#7e7e7e;
        font-size: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        width:70px;
        height:35px;
        line-height:35px;
        margin:auto;
        border-radius:1px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all .5s;
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
    .inner-wrapper:hover .item-overlay-text {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    .inner-wrapper .page-overlay {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0; 
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
        z-index: 2;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .inner-wrapper #page-overlay {
        opacity:0;
        transition: all .5s;
        pointer-events:none;
    }
    .inner-wrapper .page-overlay .text{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        font-size: 50px;
        color: white;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
    .inner-wrapper .page-overlay .text .close{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        color:#000;
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-top:5px;
        padding-right:5px;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1301px){
        .inner-wrapper{
            width:16.6666%;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1300px){
        .inner-wrapper{
            width:20%;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
        .inner-wrapper{
            width:25%;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
        .inner-wrapper{
            width:50%;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .inner-wrapper{
            width:100%;
        }
    }
</style>

<body> 
<div id="outer-wrapper" class="outer-wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper" class="inner-wrapper" ng-repeat="x in insideData">
        <img ng-if="x.service=='Instagram'||(x.service=='Twitter' && x.mediaType=='image')" ng-src='{{x.thumbnails[0].url}}'>
        <div class="outer-caption" ng-if="x.service=='Twitter'&& x.mediaType!='image'">
            <div class="inner-caption">{{x.caption}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-overlay-color"></div>
        <div class="item-overlay-text" ng-click="showOverlay()">VIEW</div>
        <div id="page-overlay" class="page-overlay">
                <div class="text">
                    <!-- <img ng-src='{{x.thumbnails[0].url}}'> -->
                    <img ng-src='{{x.mainImage.url}}'>
                    <span class="close" ng-click="hideOverlay()">X</span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    // Create the module
    var appModule = angular.module('appName', []);

    // Create rootScope variables
    appModule.run(
        function($rootScope){
            $rootScope.title = "Taneleer Demonstration";
        }
    );

    // Create the controller
    appModule.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.showOverlay = function(){
            document.getElementById("page-overlay").style.opacity = 1;
            document.getElementById("page-overlay").style["pointer-events"] = "auto";
        }
        $scope.hideOverlay = function(){
            document.getElementById("page-overlay").style.opacity = 0;
            document.getElementById("page-overlay").style["pointer-events"] = "none";
        }

        $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : "https://taneleer.composedcreative.com/api/v1/feed/a0329f16-9225-11e6-89bb-296a97b9d609/bb0429f6-f0ca-11e7-8f5d-d92739a9a53f"
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {

                $scope.myMessage = "Success!";

                $scope.response = response;
                $scope.meta = response.data.meta;
                $scope.outsideData = response.data;
                $scope.insideData = response.data.data;
                $scope.links = response.data.links;

                $scope.selfLink = response.data.links.self;
                $scope.firstLink = response.data.links.first;
                $scope.lastLink = response.data.links.last;
                $scope.nextLink = response.data.links.next;
                $scope.prevLink = response.data.links.prev;

                $scope.statuscode = response.status;
                $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
                $scope.statusheaders = response.headers(); 
                $scope.statusconfig = response.config;   

            }, function myError(response) {
                $scope.myMessage = "Error!";
                $scope.response = response;
                $scope.statuscode = response.status;
                $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
                $scope.statusheaders = response.headers(); 
                $scope.statusconfig = response.config;   
            });


        $scope.getNext = function() {
            $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : $scope.nextLink
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {

                $scope.myMessage = "Success!";
                $scope.response = response;
                $scope.outsideData = response.data;
                $scope.meta = response.data.meta;

                $scope.insideData = $scope.insideData.concat(response.data.data);

                $scope.links = response.data.links;
                $scope.selfLink = response.data.links.self;
                $scope.firstLink = response.data.links.first;
                $scope.lastLink = response.data.links.last;
                $scope.nextLink = response.data.links.next;
                $scope.prevLink = response.data.links.prev;

                $scope.statuscode = response.status;
                $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
                $scope.statusheaders = response.headers(); 
                $scope.statusconfig = response.config;   

            }, function myError(response) {
                $scope.myMessage = "Error!";
                $scope.response = response;
                $scope.statuscode = response.status;
                $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
                $scope.statusheaders = response.headers(); 
                $scope.statusconfig = response.config;   
            });
        }
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                $scope.getNext();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hiding it via `id` which is so wrong, `id` must be unique at all times

Here's a quick solution

Try this:

add this styles because we're gonna use angular directive called `ng-class`

```
.show {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.hide{
    opacity: 0 !important; 
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

in your html file, use `ng-init` to create a scope variable of your `ng-repeat`
which handles the show/hide, I didn't remove the `id's` its your job to clean it

```
<div id="outer-wrapper" class="outer-wrapper">          
        <div id="inner-wrapper" class="inner-wrapper" ng-repeat="x in insideData" ng-init="show = false">
            <img ng-if="x.service=='Instagram'||(x.service=='Twitter' && x.mediaType=='image')" ng-src='{{x.thumbnails[0].url}}'>
            <div class="outer-caption" ng-if="x.service=='Twitter'&& x.mediaType!='image'">
                <div class="inner-caption">{{x.caption}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-overlay-color"></div>
            <!--We do this because we don't have reference of show in the controller-->
            <div class="item-overlay-text" ng-click="show = true">VIEW</div>
            <!--In here we handle the show and hide-->
          <div id="page-overlay" class="page-overlay" ng-class="{'show': show, 'hide': !show}">
             <div class="text">
                 <img ng-src='{{x.mainImage.url}}'>
                 <span class="close" ng-click="show = false">X</span>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```